# Variable not being set correctly

Tags: excel, vba

Hopefully this is something an expert will see straight away but I cannot for the life of me see the problem!
In the code below I set reccount as follows:

```
reccount = 
lookupSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
```

but sometimes when I run the code I get the record count from another worksheet??

```vb
Option Explicit
        
Sub Update_AmazonMatches()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Update Master Supplier With  Matches"
    '=============================================
    'Update Amazon Matches
    Dim lookupSheet As Worksheet
    Dim AmzDataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ImpAmzDataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim updateSheet As Worksheet
    Dim updaterow As Range
    Dim valuetocheck As String
    Dim Brand As String
    Dim Category As String
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim LastRowUpdate As Long
    Dim LastRowLookup As Long
    Dim DateUpd As Date
    Dim lookupTbl As ListObject
    Dim updateTbl As ListObject
    Dim reccount As Long
    Dim recs As String
    Dim AmzDataTbl As ListObject
    Dim visrange As Range
    
    Set lookupSheet = Worksheets("DATA - Barcode List")
    Set updateSheet = Worksheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    Set AmzDataSheet = Worksheets("DATA - Amazon Data")
    Set ImpAmzDataSheet = Worksheets("IMPORT - Amazon Data Import")
    
    Set lookupTbl = lookupSheet.ListObjects("BCODE_Table")
    Set AmzDataTbl = AmzDataSheet.ListObjects("AmazonDataTable")
    Set updateTbl = updateSheet.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    DateUpd = Date
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    updateSheet.Unprotect
    lookupSheet.Unprotect
    'get the number of the last row with data for both tables
    
    LastRowUpdate = updateSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowLookup = lookupSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
    '=============================================================================================
    'Ensure all data is showing in Barcode Table
    With lookupTbl
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
     End With
      
    'Enure all data is showing in Master Supplier  Table
    With updateTbl
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
        
    '=============================================================================================
    'Delete No Match items from Barcode table then resefilter
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With lookupSheet.ListObjects("BCODE_Table").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="No Match"
        Set visrange = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .AutoFilter
        On Error Resume Next
        visrange.Delete
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
    With lookupTbl
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
    '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
    '**' I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY SOMETIMES RECCOUNT IS THE LAST EMPTY CELL FROM LOOKUPSHEET
    'AND OTHER TIMES IT IS LAST ROW FROM UPDATESHEET**
    
    '+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
    reccount = _
    lookupSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
    recs = reccount
    MsgBox "Number of Matches to update " + recs, vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
    If reccount > 1000 Then
    MsgBox "Number of records Matched is over 1,000 and may take minute or more to "
    process ", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE"
    End If
    
    
    'For each record in the Barcode table - lookup Master Supplier Key in Supplier file
    'and update Amazon Match and Date last match checked fields
    Dim lkup As String
    Dim lkupres As Variant
    
    For l = 6 To LastRowLookup
    'look for the value in supplier key in Master Supplier file
    
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing Amazon Matches"
        '& Round((l / LastRowLookup) * 100) & "%"
        
        lkup = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 3)
        Brand = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 5)
        Category = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 6)
        '
        Set updaterow = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File").Range("a1:r" & _
        LastRowUpdate).Find(lkup)
        If Not updaterow Is Nothing Then
            updateSheet.Cells(updaterow.Row, 18).Value = DateUpd
            updateSheet.Cells(updaterow.Row, 17).Value = "Match"
            updateSheet.Cells(updaterow.Row, 19).Value = Brand
            updateSheet.Cells(updaterow.Row, 20).Value = Category
        End If
    Next l
    
    MsgBox "Amazon Match Update Completed.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
    'Update date last No Match checked
    Dim Matchtype As Variant
    
    Matchtype = lookupSheet.Range("b3").Value
    If Matchtype = "Previous No Match Items" Then
        Dim supplierSheet As Worksheet
        Dim MapSheet As Worksheet
        Dim valueToSearch As String
        Dim tt As Integer, mm As Integer
    
        Set MapSheet = Worksheets("MAPPINGS - Map Fields")
        Set supplierSheet = Worksheets("DATA - Active Suppliers")
    
        'get the number of the last row with data i
        LastRowUpdate = supplierSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Application.StatusBar = "Updating Active Supplier File"
    
        'look for the value in column A of Active Suppliers
        For mm = 2 To LastRowUpdate
            'if found a match, copy column B value to sheet1 and proceed to the next
            'Value
            If supplierSheet.Cells(mm, 1) = lookupSheet.Range("b2") Then
                DateUpd = Date
                supplierSheet.Cells(mm, 15).Value = DateUpd
                Exit For
            End If
        Next mm
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = "Clearing Amazon Data File"
    
    If Not AmzDataTbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        AmzDataTbl.DataBodyRange.Delete
        AmzDataTbl.Resize Range("A1:e2")
    End If
ProcessEnd:
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    updateSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True
    lookupSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Debug your code with F8 step by step and see the exact moment you get the wrong recount

Comment: Also note that you have two `On Error Resume Next` lines which are never reset so you will be unaware of any errors in your code. Really bad idea.

Comment: the issue is at the MSGBOX "Number of Matches to update" - if i define the variable right before the msgbox statement how can it be differing?

Comment: ok i think I see what is issue - if i run the code with the update sheet open it picks up the count from there....so do i need to activate the correct worksheet before the setting of the variable?  Why does it not pick it up from the lookupsheet reference....reccount = 
    lookupSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

Comment: You don't need a string variable to display the value btw, you can just use `MsgBox "Number of Matches to update " & reccount, vbInformation, PROC_TITLE`. As for the incorrect amount, I have done it with the lookupsheet active and different sheet active and I keep getting the correct value. Never the lastrow since that's not what that code is for but the expected result nonetheless. Your `Application.Statusbar = ""` will keep it as "" regardless of what you're doing, you need to use `Application.Statusbar = False` instead to reset it.

Comment: At the line `.reccount = lookupSheet.AutoFilter.Range.etc` does the `lookupSheet` have an `AutoFilter` applied ? You seem to be using both `lookupSheet` and `lookupTbl` to apply/reset filter which is confusing. I suspect the `On Error Resume Next` is masking the real error.

Comment: If you want the number of rows in `lookupTbl` after the "No Match" deletions then try `reccount = lookupTbl.ListRows.Count`

Comment: yes there is a filter set before where i filter all no match statuses and deleted them... i then reset the filter so all remaining records are shown and it is this count i want..should I have ON Error Go To 0 in to rest the error handling?

Comment: That's how you reset the error handling yes, also I edited your code to get rid of empty space/fix  the indentations but there were also a couple of lines where you'd need the ` _` to continue on the next line which I hope were on one line before in your actual code, if not fix that, please. Same for your comments on multiple lines needing the ` before the next line as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the error handling with `On Error Goto 0`.

```vb
    With lookupTbl
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="No Match"
        On Error Resume Next
        Set visrange = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not visrange Is Nothing Then
            visrange.Delete
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter
        reccount = .ListRows.Count
    End With
    
    If reccount > 1000 Then
        MsgBox reccount & " Matches to update " & vbLf _
        & "this may take minute or more to process ", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox reccount & " Matches to update ", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
```